# How can I use "import something from package" in script starting from electron-quick-start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am new to electron. So far I can run electron-quick-start but I get stuck when try using

```
import {somthing} from "package"
```

Here is what I did from electron-quick-start.

1. Edit ./renderer.js as

```
import { TitleBar } from "electron-react-titlebar";
import "electron-react-titlebar/assets/style.css";

ReactDOM.render(<TitleBar />, document.querySelector("title-bar"));
```

2. index.html:

```
...
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src https://www.google-analytics.com 'self' file://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
</head>
<body>
  <title-bar></title-bar>
...
```

3. main.js (seems I need to change loadFile to loadURL)

```
...
  mainWindow.loadURL(`File://${__dirname}/index.html`);
  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
...
```

After this I get an error

```
renderer.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I did some research by setting

```
"type": "module"
```

in package.json, and this gets errors about module/commonjs.

I then find other projects when importing modules they write requires in

```
    <script>require("./renderer")</script>
```

but I got

```
index.html:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Then I tried babel / browserify and many other things only to find my simple test project messed up.

I googled for ES6-react-electron sample minimal projects but they are too out-dated that I find many deprecated packages. These projects still get errors

**So, can someone make a modernized minimal example which starts from electron-quick-start and**

```
1. use "import" in script
2. (optional) somehow use "require" to import other modules in index.html
```

I believe the example should be quite simple but I just missed some points.
Best if somebody can just post a GitHub repo that everybody else can starts happy coding from just pulling it! Thanks!